# Android app-only fingerprint authentication

Tags: java, android, fingerprint, biometrics

I am currently following this guide: https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/biometric-auth, and using android 11 to test it.

I want to use fingerprint authentication in my app, however the code from the link above works only with the fingerprint that is stored on the device. Meaning it doesn't work unless you have set up fingerprint authentication as your lock screen.

Is it possible to store fingerprint credentials in an android app which will be independent of the device's fingerprint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to store fingerprint credentials in an android app which will be independent of the device's fingerprint?

No, sorry, not with stock Android biometrics support.

Comment: This is incredibly frustrating since I don't want my app to force the user to modify their lock settings. Thank you for the quick reply.